# Rigorous Definition of a Complexity Class

Tags: complexity-classes

From Wikipedia, "Complexity classes are sets of related computational problems. They are defined in terms of the computational difficulty of solving the problems contained within them with respect to particular computational resources like time or memory. More formally, the definition of a complexity class consists of three things: a type of computational problem, a model of computation, and a bounded computational resource."

Class P and NP seem to fit this definition exactly.

However, when I look at classes like #P: it seems to me just like a set of related computational problems put together that have not been assigned a complexity class yet, as we do not define time and space resources for them.

I am wondering: in theory, can I just take a set of two problems and call it a complexity class (even it if may be a useless one)?. Is there a rigorous definition to what constitutes a complexity class? If so, what is it?

Comment: *Complexity class* is an informal concept. It doesn't have any formal defintion.

Comment: I don't completely agree with Yuval. I would define a "decision complexity class" as a set of languages, in which case, yes, you could take a set of two decision problems and call it a complexity class. This definition generalizes to sets of functions of the form $f: \{0,1\}^* \to \mathbb{N}$, which captures $\#P$, and to sets of functions with other ranges.

Comment: @HuckBennett, as I understand a complexity class is a set of problems of the same "type" where type refers to either being a decision problem or a function problem, etc?

Comment: I think you can think of it that way, yes.